# Android betterpickers: Force order of DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: android, datepicker

Seems betterpickers picks the dateformat from device locale to show the sequence of picking the MM->DD->YYYY to be set by users.
Is there any way that we can force for DD->MM->YYYY always i.e first Day, then month and then year?

Thanks,
Raminder